# PHP addition operation

Tags: java, php, types, addition

I have an addition operation that I am executing in both in Java and in PHP.

In **Java** summing up **int(334420379)** with **int(1825406976)** results in **int(-2135139941)**.
In **PHP** summing the same values results in **double(2159827355)**.

How can I replicate the Java results in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the intval() method in php

```
$v1 = 334420379;
$v2 = 1825406976;
$res = intval($v1+$v2);
```

it will return you the desired result

```
-2135139941
```